# How to turn off the Multicast DNS and Multicast UPNP Services in Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, services

I just wonder how to turn off those 2 services completly since I've got no use for them as they are a security risk in my case. Cause I've got a local device for which I can't Block upnp and that device is using the multicast ip range and the multicast dns can be accessed cause of the problem mentioned above.

Sure I could just block it in the router but I wonder if its possible to just disable it, os wise.

As I googled I found something concerning the stopping of the multicast dns service, instructions were as follows:

```
# chkconfig --level3 avahi-daemon off
# service avahi-daemon stop
```

Don't know how to check if its disabled now tho. so I would appreciate it if someone could tell me how to turn off these 2 services?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
nano /etc/init/avahi-daemon.conf
```

Search for the following lines, edit the line with “start on” and add “never and”:

Replace the line

```
start on (filesystem and started dbus)
```

with

```
start on (never and filesystem and started dbus)
stop on stopping dbus
```