# How to prevent my computer from sending multicast requests

Tags: avahi

I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 and shortly noticed that my internet port has been blocked by internet provider. I contacted technical support and get reported that my computer was sending too many multicast requests. And their automated system blocked my port.

I've disabled avahi-daemon on my computer:

executed the command:

```
gksu gedit /etc/default/avahi-daemon
```

and then set the parameter:

```
AVAHI_DAEMON_DETECT_LOCAL=0
```

and saved the file.

After that I disabled MULTICAST on my network card:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 -multicast
```

My question: Are those measures enough or I need to do additional steps to prevent my computer from sending multicast requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your method may work, these steps will certainly disable multicast:

You can try to edit the Init file for the Avahi daemon to just block it from even starting up.

Steps:

1. Open `/etc/init/avahi-daemon.conf` in your favorite text editor as root.
2. Find the line with `start on (filesystem and started dbus)`.
3. Replace that line with `start on (never and filesystem and started dbus)`.
4. If there is not a `stop` line, skip to step 6.
5. Replace the `stop` line with `stop on stopping dbus`.
6. (Only do this step if you didn't do 5) Add `stop on stopping dbus` to the end of the file
7. Reboot

[(Src)](https://askubuntu.com/a/434773/208574)

Comment: setting `AVAHI_DAEMON_DETECT_LOCAL=0` is not enough? Am I right ?

Comment: I don't think so. That appears to only disable local daemon detection. I don't really know though. I never paid too much attention to Avahi.

Comment: no prob! Glad I could help.